# Yii 2 и организация кода

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, yii2

Недавно начал знакомиться с Yii 2 и возник вопрос по организации кода, разработчики предлагают два шаблона [basic](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic) и [advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced).

Мне бы хотелось большей обособленности для различных частей проекта (модульности), чтобы каждый модуль (user, article, whatever) содержал код как админской так и пользовательской части, набор виджетов. В идеале хотелось бы, чтобы эти модули можно было ставить как зависимости проекта через composer.

Сейчас смотрю в сторону расширений, но не уверен, правильно ли их так использовать.

Есть ли у вас какие-нить идеи на этот счет, может кто-то уже использует что-то похожее?

Comment: Это называется [модулями](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-modules.md), но сам Yii зачастую провоцирует неделимую структуру.

Comment: Да, модули то что нужно, но есть ли возможность ставить их через composer? В принципе это может быть расширение, которое содержит модуль (или даже несколько), но нормально ли это?

Comment: модули вроде adldap спокойно ставятся через composer. но нужно уметь их создавать (отдельный репозитарий на github)